# SAP Hybris Marketing / Access Partner ID in email action

Tags: abap, sap-marketing-cloud

I am customizing the Hybris marketing email personalisation in class `CL_CUAN_MKT_EXEC_EXECUTE_EMAIL` (Superclass `CL_CUAN_MKT_EXEC_EXECUTE_ACTN`).

I wonder if I can access the Business Partner IDs of the target group members within this class. I could only manage to find the member key in *MT_TG_MEMBERS* (length 16), but I need the Partner ID (length 10). In the email action the member key is stored in lt_pers_content (see screenshot).

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check table **lt_exec_member_status**. It contains the **CONTACT_KEY** and the TG_MEMBER_KEY. This way you can find out the CONTACT_KEY which gives you the key to the Business Partner.